# Installing and running visual studio executable on an Apple computer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

I am debating creating a simple project through Visual Studio on a Windows computer for a couple of my friends. However I know that a couple of them own an Apple computer instead of Windows. I was wondering (before I get to far) if it is possible (without installing other software like Parallels, etc) to install my executable so they can use it along with the supporting database structure (open to anything free or comes with Visual Studio) on their Apple computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that without extra software. However you don't need to run Parallels with a full install of Windows.

You can try CrossOver. It lets you run Windows applications within OS X. I've use it a fair bit to play old PC games from my childhood. Works well.
http://www.codeweavers.com/products/

Comment: It looks like you have to pay for Code Weavers. Is there some other cheaper way you know? Its just for a simple .net program.